# Repeating the rows within Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, while-loop

I'm working on a WordPress posts loop with same rows repeating. I achieved the first row but the 2nd row isn't looping whereas the first row loops perfectly.

Below is the code for the loop and the screenshot.

[image: Actual Layout I want to achieve]

**Loop Code**

```
$count = 1;

$featured_posts = new \WP_Query( $args );
if ( $featured_posts->have_posts() ) : while ($featured_posts->have_posts()) : $featured_posts->the_post();
    if ( 1 == $count % 5 ) {
        echo '<div class="wh-tiles-posts-left">';
    } elseif ( 2 == $count % 5 ) {
        echo '<div class="wh-tiles-posts-right">';
    } elseif ( 4 == $count % 9 ) {
        echo '<div class="wh-tiles-posts-left2">';
    } elseif ( 5 == $count % 10 ) {
        echo '<div class="wh-tiles-posts-right2">';
    }
    $this->render_post_body( $count );

    if ( 1 == $count % 5  ) {
        echo '</div>';
    } elseif ( 3 == $count % 6 ) {
        echo '</div>';
    } elseif( 4 == $count % 9 ) {
        echo '</div>';
    } elseif ( 5 == $count % 10 ) {
        echo '</div>';
    }
    $count++;

    endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

What am I doing wrong?. The div with class names output shown in the image 2 below for better explanation.

[image: Image with classnames]

Comment: I'd use [css grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) for this. COnsider using `elseif` tp chain your conditions rather than sequential `if`s & lastly, reorganize the cde... There's too many opening & closing php tags & it's a little hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's to do with your calculations as to when to add the various div tags, I've changed the calculations, especially only having 1 close test...

```
if ( 0 == ($count-1) % 5 ) {
    echo '<div class="wh-tiles-posts-left">';
} elseif ( 1 == ($count-1) % 5 ) {
    echo '<div class="wh-tiles-posts-right">';
} elseif ( 3 == ($count-1) % 5 ) {
    echo '<div class="wh-tiles-posts-left2">';
} elseif ( 4 == ($count-1) % 5 ) {
    echo '<div class="wh-tiles-posts-right2">';
}
$this->render_post_body( $count );

if ( 1 != ($count-1) % 5 ) {
    echo '</div>';
}
```