# Count row and repeat the same rows within Loop

Tags: php, loops

I'm working on mansory gallery here images fetching into the row first row contains three images and then for the second row contains two images and so on.
Now currently all images coming inside same row. I want to add in a loop I had tried but unable to achieve the result. For [inspiration link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53543851/9004424)

```
<?php
  include('admin/config.php');
  $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM gallery order by id desc");
 // var_dump($result->num_rows); 

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<div class='gallery-items'>";
    echo "<div class='mansory-item'>";
        echo "<a href='admin/images/".$row['path']."' data-lightbox='gallery' class='ansa-thumb'>";
            echo "<img src='admin/images/".$row['path']."' class='item-img img-1'>";
        echo "</a>";
    echo "</div>";
  echo "</div>";
  }
?>
```

Current output

[image: current]

Expected output

[image: expected]

Can anyone suggest me how should i get this output.

Comment: How many images are there? 6? like 3,2,1 in each row?

Comment: @Rahul I have total of 10 images.

Comment: @Rahul first row contain 3 images and second-row contain two images. like this same for all 3,2 3,2

Comment: Please check my answer. Tested and verified.

Comment: @Rahul your code showing infinite loop with the same row multiple images as i'm getting currently.

Comment: I made changes already. Once refresh the page and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below snippet,

```
$inc   = 4;
$i     = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (empty($temp) || $inc != $temp) {
        $temp = $inc;
        if ($inc == 4) {
            echo "<div class='gallery-grid'>";
        }
        echo "<div class='gallery-items'>";
    }
    if ($i <= $inc) {
        // echo $i . '<>';
        echo "<div class='mansory-item'>";
        echo "<a href='admin/images/" . $row['username'] . "' data-lightbox='gallery' class='ansa-thumb'>";
        echo "<img src='admin/images/" . $row['username'] . "' class='item-img img-1'>";
        echo "</a>";
        echo "</div>";
        $i++;
    }
    if ($i == $inc) {
        echo "</div>";
        if ($i == 3) {
            echo "</div>";
        }
        $i   = 1;
        $inc = ($inc == 4 ? 3 : 4);
    }
}
```

Comment: After one loop for the second repeat loop can we add `id="ansa-load"` for the second iteration coming loop, is it possible.

Comment: You mean when `mansory-item` class count inside `gallery-items` will be 2 ?

Comment: No i'm talking about complete row 3,2 and the same iteration 3,2 here these rows i'm wrapping into one parent div `masonry-grid`  <div class=masonry-grid>3,2</div> and again same <div class=masonry-grid here want to appent id>3,2</div>

Comment: Ok I am checking

Comment: @Husna I made changes. Please consider upvoting the answer cuz.. you can. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198703/discussion-between-husna-and-rahul).